# Can the sum of two subsets without a maximal element have a maximal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm strugling to prove the following:

> Let A, B ⊂ R be two bounded subsets, neither of which has a maximal
> element. Can their “sum”, i.e. A + B = {a + b s.t. a ∈ A, b ∈ B} have
> a maximal element?

I know the answer is NO, it doesn't. **Since neither is bounded above, then the sum shouldn't be bounded avobe either**. Another thing that comes to my mind is that the sum of two open sets is an open sets, but I don't know if the openess of a set is related to the fact that it's not bounded. (for me proving a set is open implies using balls).

Am I right with my answer (since neither is bounded above, then the sum shouldn't be bounded avobe either). How could I write it in mathematical terms/language?

Thank you very much in advance, I really appreciate your help since it's my first time dealing with sets and topology.

Comment: They are both bounded above.  In $\mathbb{R}$ a maximal element is in fact a maximum since it is totally ordered. You can easily show that the supremum of the sum is equal to the sum of the supremums,  and that element is not achieved

Comment: "B has no maximal element" means no member (element) of B is equal to max(B). It does not imply that B has no upper bound. [0,1) has no maximal element.

Answer (score 1):

If $\max (A)$ does not exist then $$c\in A+B\implies \exists a\in A\,\exists b\in B\,(c=a+b)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists a,a'\in A\,\exists b\in B\,(a<a'\land c=a+b)\implies$$  $$\implies \exists a,a'\in A\,\exists b\in B\,( a<a'\land c=a+b<a'+b\in A+B)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists a'\in A\,\exists b\in B\,(c<a'+b\in A+B)\implies$$ $$\implies c\ne \max (A+B).$$

b

Answer (score 0):

If $m=\max(A+B)$, take $a_m\in A$ and $b_m\in B$ such that $m=a_m+b_m$ suppose that there is $a\in A$ such that $a>a_m$. Then $a+b_m>a_m+b_m=m$, which is impossible, since $a+b_m\in A+B$ and $m=\max(A+B)$. So, $a_m=\max A$, but you are assuming that $A$ has no maximum.